# Why is wp_nav_menu() not remove the div container from the menu?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to remove the `<div>` that wraps the `<ul>`, but when I set `'container'` to `false` or `''` the `<div>` still shows up. Why is it not being removed?

Example with `false`:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation navigation">
  <?php wp_nav_menu(
            array( 'theme_location'=> 'header-menu',
                   'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
                   'container' => false,
                   'depth' => 2, ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

Example with `''`:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation navigation">
  <?php wp_nav_menu(
            array( 'theme_location'=> 'header-menu',
                   'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
                   'container' => '',
                   'depth' => 2, ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Define the UL as your container

```
wp_nav_menu(
array( 'theme_location'=> 'header-menu',
'menu_id' => 'header-menu',
'container' => "ul",
'depth' => 2, ) );
```